# How to use axios securely with laravel passport on the same laravel app

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication, axios, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel backend ready with all the required API's, An android app is consuming them, Now I want an async page with vuejs since I have to use API's I have to use Axios. But because I have passport installed I have to expose user's sensitive data in js,

as js is client-sided language anyone with a bit knowledge of web development can just view the source of the page and get mail address and password of the currently authenticated user. And more importantly, client secret also is being exposed. What can I do in this case?

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sending the page to someone who **isn't** the currently authenticated user? Does it matter if they can see their own email address? Or the token that *they* have to send to continue to show who they are?

Comment: @Quentin No, the page is accessible to authenticated users only. To answer your second question no it doesn't matter but I don't want any vulnerability in my web app.

Comment: My point is that giving people information that they already have is not a vulnerability!

Comment: @Quentin One person is logged in on a computer, can't anyone else just view the page source, why are you assuming that it's the intended user accessing the computer every time?

Comment: If the problem is a user logging in and then leaving their computer unattended then you need to look at securing things with timeouts not by refusing to give the user information they already have.

Answer (score -2):

You can build a middleware to inject the client details into your request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class InjectClientIdAndSecret
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $client = DB::table('oauth_clients')
            ->where('password_client', 1)
            ->first();

        $request->json()->add([
            'client_id' => $client->id,
            'client_secret' => $client->secret,
            'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try this. Thanks for answering.